# Laravel Security - Add users to a group (Good Practices)

Tags: laravel, security

I let an authenticated user to add more users to a group. This happens by sending the user's ID to my controller (it can be an array). I add every single user to the group by ID.

I'm worried about security terms. I would'nt like someone to guess an ID and send that info to me.

Is there a proper way to do this?

I'm only showing those users that have privacy as public (if that helps)

Comment: How they can pass the ID's ? By just putting the ID's only or by clicking the button or checkbox and send it to your controller as post request ?

Comment: Read about [gates and policies](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization).

Comment: @Qonvex620 Well, Im working with API's. So yeah, I provide the user with available users with their ID's and they send that as a post request. In the frontend they can use checkboxes and the ID's get passed in an array.

Comment: @Tpojka Thank you buddy, I'll give it a read.